# Alternative for "seats" in expressions such as "40% of the total seats are reserved for students of backward cast"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, nouns, word-usage, synonyms

All of the leading educational institutes have 60% of their seats reserved for students of backward castes. It is a fairly common expression and a sad fact in India.

What would be an alternative to the word "seat" in this sentence? Even though it is very popular here, I am sure it has been used incorrectly because I did not find any meaning for the word "seat" which could be used over here.

Comment: 'Seat' is very understandable but not the first word that eould be expected in BrE or AmE. Which castes are the 'backwards' ones?

Comment: @Mitch the ones that would be considered to be untouchable and slave 100 years back.

Comment: @Mitch yes I know it is common in AmE or BrE, that is why I want to its alternative

Comment: I think *seat* is OK for this in AmE.  Here is a recent news story: "Harvard interviewed about 2,200 candidates and accepted about 1,100 to fill its 905-910 available seats."

Comment: I'd say seats would be understood, but in Aus, you'd find it more common to hear `places`

Answer (score 9):

Higher Education institutions offer ***places*** in the UK. It may be the same in other regions.

I might prefer *lower caste* for *backward cast* but that wasn't part of the question.

Comment: I do agree that saying ‘backward’ is quite offensive.  But now that I look at it, is using *cast* for *caste* even normal?

Comment: Keep in mind that we're dealing with sensitive/PC-inflected terminology in another culture. India appears to have adopted "backward" to get away from "lower". When that becomes exhausted as a euphemism, they'll cycle to another one - just like we do, but in a different sequence.

Comment: @StoneyB Yes, but this is essentially "translating" from Indian English into another dialect, so a regional use of "backward" may also need to be changed, just as "seat" needs to be.

Comment: Lower income families surely is a more socially acceptable phrase than *lower caste*? I don't like that phrase at all.

Comment: Aha! It appears that "Backward" is a term enshrined in the [Indian Constitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Other_Backward_Castes#Obligation_of_the_government)

Comment: @spiceyokooko  But *caste* is the fact with which OP is dealing, and that denotes religious and social status as well as economic status. "Affirmative Action" (the US equivalent of Indian "Reservation") similarly is addressed to populations defined by race and ethnicity, not only income.

Comment: @StoneyB Yes. I noticed from your link that all women in India are considered to be backward! Very strange.

Comment: @spiceyokooko  Indian English appears to use "backward" in much the same way contemporary US English uses "disadvantaged". I expect entirely new terms in both by 2025.

Comment: @StoneyB Let's not giggle at contemporary US English! Oh alright then, let's giggle! ;-)

Comment: @StoneyB "Affirmative Action" in the US is _not_ the equivalent of "Reservation" in India. Affirmative action does not _reserve_ positions for those meeting certain criteria (minority status etc.) and _require_ that those positions _must_ be filled by those who meet the criteria. If no applicants meet the criteria, or all candidates who meet the criteria and are offered the position(s) turn down the job, it can be filled by someone else. In the reservation system in India, reserved seats cannot be offered to, or filled by, those who do not meet the criteria.

Comment: @Dilip That is quite true, and my choice of word was poor; affirmative action is "parallel" rather than "equivalent" to reservation. I wanted only to emphasize that the relevant criteria in both are not exclusively or even primarily economic.

Comment: @stoneyB: I think 2025 is much too long from now. The word "underrepresented" is already replacing "disadvantaged".

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest ***enrollments***, or perhaps *admissions*.

Answer (score 1):

You might say that they reserve 60% of their *openings* or *positions* to members of the lower classes.

Answer (score 1):

Over here in Aus you might also hear **intake** being used to refer to the overall group/period/people entering university so you could say that 60% of the institution's target intake is reserved?

Sample usage : [RMIT's mid-year intake](http://www.rmit.edu.au/browse/Study%20at%20RMIT/Midyear%20intake/) or [Monash's 2005 key dates](http://www.monash.edu.au/students/dates/principal-dates-2005.html) (Fri 31, Dec 2004 is the last day of the Feb intake).

Answer (score 0):

All of the leading educational institutes have 60% of their **quotas** reserved for students of backward castes.